# drop shadow to remain at bottom of rotating uiview swift 3

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

How do you keep a shadow at the bottom of a rotating/ animating ui view

my code for the drop shadow is as follows

```
    extension UIView {

    func dropShadow(cornerRadius : CGFloat, heightOffset : Int) {

        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: heightOffset)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
//remove bezier to enable corner radius
       // self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    }
}
```

then in my view controller I call the method in a uiview animation

to hide

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            for views in self.menuView.subviews {
                views.alpha = 0
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.moreButton.transform = tr
              self.moreButton.dropShadow(cornerRadius: self.moreButton.layer.cornerRadius, heightOffset: 5)


        }
```

to show

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            self.moreButton.dropShadow(cornerRadius: self.moreButton.layer.cornerRadius, heightOffset: -5)

           // menuV.center = self.menuView.center
            menuV.center.y = -30
            menuV.alpha = 1
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


            self.moreButton.transform = tr


        }, completion: { (complete) in


        })
```

the result is that the shadow jumps to the top or bottom and then rotates around.

I basically need it to remain at the bottom of the layer at all times during the animation.

could somebody please help and describe what I'm possibly doing wrong

regards

Thomas

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer : -

Rather then rotate the button as a whole it made sense to only rotate the image within the button

so the code should be like this

```
            self.myButton.imageView?.transform = tr
```